# Laravel routes not working when using Vue Router

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to call a laravel route `Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');` that will logout the user and redirect to the login page, but when I try to redirect to this url it won't work, anything happens, just like it was calling a vue router route, but this route does not exists in my `router.js`.

This is my route configuration to vue routes:

```
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('vue_capture', '^(?!storage).*$');
```

and this is my `router.js` :

```
//import ...

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [{
        path: '/',
        component: Inicio
    }, {
        path: '/viagens/cadastrar',
        component: Cadastrar
    }, {
        path: '/viagens/listar',
        component: Listar
    }]
})
```

There's not a `/logout` route in my `route.js`, so why it is not calling my laravel route??

Comment: I don't understand ... Where are you calling the laravel logout route?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ in a button link, but even directly in the URL it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you generating your links inside your vue component: with `router-link` or `href` ?

- If you want to call a vue route, use `router-link`;
- If you want to call a "normal" or laravel route, use `href`;

Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your vue routes
before this line:-

```
Auth::routes();
```

Comment: can you add to your answer why this would fix their issue? because this should be before the catchall route not after it

Answer (score 0):

First, add Laravel auth routes to web.php file in routes folder

```
Auth::routes();
```

then in the frontend send a request to logout route

```
  axios.post('/logout').then(response => {
                location.reload();
            }).catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: I can do post requests like this, but I'm trying to do a get request to a laravel route through URL. What should I do in this case?

Comment: are you using Laravel Passport?

Comment: No, I'm using laravel's default Auth adapter.

Comment: try this in your route file `Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');`

Answer (score 0):

What I did in myproject.There is Auth::routes() in web.php. It will handle it by calling ougout in AthenticatesUser.php.Please have a look at this php class.

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn" @click="logout">logout</button>
    <form id="logout-form" action="/logout" method="POST" style="display: 
none;">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="token">
                    </form>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>
 <script>
  export default {
  computed: {
        token() {
            let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
            return token.content
        }
    },
    methods: {
        logout() {
            document.getElementById('logout-form').submit()
        }
    }
}
```